# How to read div innerHTML by SSJS

Tags: xpages

I set my div content by CSJS like this:

```
var myDIVObj = dojo.byId("myDivID");
myDIVObj.innerHTML = "Hello world!";
```

then how do I read it by SSJS?

```
getComponent("myDivID").innerHTML ????
```

Thank you

Comment: This question is not related to xpages, but rather you need to understand the behavior of a server/client application. First of all, you need to do a form post and this has to be a input field (or a hidden input field) in order for SSJS to see this information and since SSJS runs on the server, this information is only accessible when you submit this page to the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no innerHTML on the server. XPages is a JavaServerFaces (JSF) application which renders a component tree in memory. It is a tree conceptually similar to the HTML DOM tree, but not consisting of HTML elements, but JSF components. You could get child components or [traverse the whole tree](http://ovaraksin.blogspot.my/2011/12/efficient-component-tree-traversal-in.html).
The reason why there is no HTML: the component tree gets transformed only in the renderresponse phase using a renderer. While HTML is the 'usual' output, a renderer could render anything (XML, SVG, PDF etc). So your SSJS has no access to the render result. That's what client side script is for.

You can read more about the [JSF lifecycle](http://www.javabeat.net/life-cycle-of-jsf-components/) and eventually use [`.getChildren`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/1.2_MR1/docs/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getChildren%28%29) to get the inner values.

But I suspect, that your goal is something completely different. So take a step back, describe what you want to do in a new question.